Как поменять кодировку клиента в postgresql
у меня такая проблема. Что делать если в PostgreSQL в серверной части кодировка utf 8, а в клиентской части win 1251, из-за этого возникают ошибки и как теперь изменить кодировку именно в клиентской части. Вот кстати изображение, где всё четко показано.[![Вот][2]][2]

Для изменения кодировки клиента в PostgreSQL, выполните следующие шаги:

Проверьте текущую кодировку клиента:
Выполните команду SHOW client_encoding; в PostgreSQL, чтобы узнать текущую кодировку клиента.
Измените кодировку клиента:
Для изменения кодировки клиента на UTF-8, выполните следующую команду:
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
Проверьте изменения: После выполнения команды проверьте, что
кодировка клиента изменилась на UTF-8, выполнив команду
SHOW client_encoding;.
Дополнительные советы: Убедитесь, что все клиентские приложения,
подключающиеся к PostgreSQL, используют кодировку UTF-8. Если у вас
есть существующие данные в кодировке WIN 1251, вам может
потребоваться преобразовать их в UTF-8. Эти шаги помогут вам
изменить кодировку клиента в PostgreSQL и избежать ошибок, связанных
с несоответствием кодировок.

